# Can "umask" variable include a number greater than "7"?

Tags: linux, files, permissions, rhel, umask

I understand we use "umask" for setting different security levels:

| umask value | Security level | Effective permission (directory) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 022 | Permissive | 755 |
| 026 | Moderate | 751 |
| 027 | Moderate | 750 |
| 077 | Severe | 700 |

Can we set umask to `028` or any other value so that it includes a number greater than "7"?

Comment: Umask bits correspond to r w x bits so going above makes no sense.

Comment: Where did you copy that table from? The "Security level" column makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shell's `umask` command takes the permission mask as an octal number, in base 8. Base 8 only has the eight digits 0 to 7, unlike decimal (ten digits) or hexadecimal (sixteen).

So, no, you can't use `umask 028` in the shell, it doesn't mean anything. Of course the umask is just a pile of bits, a number, and it could be represented in decimal or hex too. E.g. in C code, `022` (octal) is the same number as `18` (decimal), so the system call to set umask to `022` could be written as `umask(18)`.

But given there's three permission bits (`rwx`), and three bits can represent eight different values, octal is a rather useful way to represent permission bits.

Also, it may be useful to consider umask values for what they mean with regard to permissions granted to other users, instead of single-word descriptions.